# Getting problems in saving data in mongodb with the enctype set

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

Hi I have a form like the one given below

```
<form action='/posts', method ='post',enctype='form-data'> 
    <div>
      <span>FileName :</span>
      <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>File :</span>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Submit :</span>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value ='Submit' id="editSubmit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and the corresponding method to save in mongodb is:

```
app.post('/posts', function(req, res) {
  RegProvider.save({
           filename: req.param('filename'),
                   file: req.param('file')
                 }, function(error, docs) {
              res.redirect('/');
         }); 
});
```

when i remove enctype in ejs file everything is working fine and the data is getting stored in mongodb.However when i put enctype in ejs file,nothing gets stored in monogdb.Infact when   try to retrieve the data i get undefined values for filename and file from fiels.Is it possible to have enctype and store data in database.If yes how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) encoding?

As far as I know you will have to parse the request as multipart message. There is Node.js plugin for that: [Multipart-js](https://github.com/isaacs/multipart-js/).

Comment: I use the multipart plugin in my file yet the only problem that i get is when i use enctype in my ejs file:                        <form action='/posts', method ='post',enctype='/multipart/form-data'>.                                                       however if i remove enctype everything works fine.